# Is there a design pattern for an object with a field that specifies the type of task to run?

Tags: design-patterns, rust

I am creating a web server in which the interface is a JSON object that contains a type field that indicates the task type to run. Is there a design pattern or a module that is commonly used to solve this problem?

Comment: *or a module* — "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, **software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow"

Comment: Also, your question does not contain any detail. I would guess, use enum and serde.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Factory Pattern](https://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html) can help.

```
fn task_factory(task_type: string) {
    match task_type {
        "task_id_1" => fn() { //task 1 },
        _ => fn() { //default }
    }
}
```

BTW, I'm not sure about the syntax but the concept is you can create something like a simple match/switch where you can list down the possible tasks, then return which ever task you need to do based on the task type.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an actual answer. Please extend your answer with a little example and some points from your link.

Comment: Right, sorry about that.. Still getting used to this.. I will edit my answer, and thanks for the correction :)

Comment: The OP has asked for Rust help. The code you've provided is not valid Rust.